# can model attributes be altered by a hacker? Spring, Java

Tags: java, spring, parameters, model

In my approute /edit RequestMethod.GET

I put the value customerId into the model
model.addAttribute("customerId",customerId);

Then the view (form method="POST") sends the data to the approute /edit RequestMethod.POST

I needed customerId in the post approute so within the form I had a hidden input for customerId.  I've found that I don't even need the hidden input.  (actually if I use a hidden input it's ignored.  The POST approute will get the original customerId that I passed to the view from the GET approute)

Suppose the user has permission to edit customerId 36 but not customerId 45.  customerId 36 is sent to the view.  Is it possible for a hacker to change customerId to 45 and edit something he doesn't have permission to edit or can I be assured customerId will still be 36?  When I was using the hidden input I had a check back in the post approute to check the user had permission to edit that customer.  Now I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Basically I don't know where the post approute is getting customerId from if I don't have it as a hidden input.  It's loaded into the model so is the model something that exists server side and it's safe or is customerId getting sent back from the user and he could manipulate it?

Comment: What you mean by "hacker"? Smb who can intercept and modify the communication between the frontend and backend? Or smb who has attack your server and gets access to your application and database? Or smb. who gets access to the frontend code, e.g. a normal user who has normal access to the frontend and attempts to do some malicious operations on data?

Comment: You seem to need to be made aware that Spring is used in countless different manners by countless different projects. What's an "approute"? How come you need to make a GET to obtain a view that you need to then POST? Explain in details the technologies you're using.

Comment: You need to learn first how HTTP works on a basic level (requests and responses), and then apply the rule that someone can write a custom HTTP client to send you _anything_ and that you can never trust the client's input.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "hacker" a user who has legitimate access to the application but attempts to do some malicious modifications of data...

On the server side you should expect that you user can send to your application **any** data in the request. Not only these can be altered data you sent before, but user can send **any** data to server, even if he didn't receive such data from server before.

On the server side you should not care about what happened before, what data you sent to user, how are data stored on the client, how some elements interoperate on the client, etc. You should **identify** the user in each request and check if this user has **permission** to do the requested operation on the requested data.

Comment: thx.  Mainly I just don't know where customerId is coming from.  I have this:
`@RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String overwriteCustomer(@ModelAttribute @Valid Customer customer, Errors errors, Model model,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "customerId") Integer customerId,`
There is no hidden input or anything in the form to send customerId so I don't know where the approute got it.  I don't know if it got sent back from the user or if it was safe and secure back on the server or in the model or the session or what.

Comment: Why you care about hidden field or not hidden field? On the server side you don't know how client constructed a request. User can create this request not only in browser but also via *curl* tool, via *postman* extension in browser or even develop a Java/Python/C# etc. client that sends such requests. It is dangerous if you do any assumptions of what user can and what cannot. User can send *any* data to your server. Check who is the current user (depending on authentication mechanism you use: OAuth2, ...), then check if this user has permission to do this operation on *these particular data*.

Comment: i want to know where customerId came from.  is it sent back to the server from the user when the user clicks OK and the form is submitted?  or is it on the server and spring checks the user and grabs customerId from the session or something?

Comment: Your original question was if a hacker can alter the data. The answer is: Yes, he can. Now you are asking how the client has generated the request. Please create a separate question for this. Also describe exactly what technologies / frameworks you use in the frontend.